# Application.Worksheetfunction.Median returns error "object doesn't support property or method"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code in which I'm taking a time and date and separating the Date and Time into two different columns and then assign the value of "A" or "B" depending on whether the result is between two time or not. Currently, it fills in the two columns but returns an error on the cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IF(cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Median("19:00:00", "06:30:00", cel.Offset(0, 2).Value)), "A", "B") portion.

```
For Each cel In src
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = VBA.Format(cel.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = VBA.Format(cel.Value, "hh:mm:ss")
    cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IF(cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Median("19:00:00", "06:30:00", cel.Offset(0, 2).Value)), "A", "B")
Next
```

How can I make this return the proper working shift "A" or "B"?

Comment: What is the value of `cel.Value` when the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

(1) Formatting a cell doesn't change it's value, only the way the data is displayed. So the cell `.offset(0, 1)` and `.offset(0, 1)` will contain the same value. If you want to check just the time part of a cell, you will have to extract it.

In VBA, you could do this for example using the function `TimeValue`, or `TimeSerial`, or you can do math: A date is internally stored as a number, the integer part representing the date, the decimal part the time. All of the following will work:

```
Dim t as Date   ' Note that there is no Time datatype in VBA
' Get the time part of a date
t = TimeValue(.offset(0, 2))
' Get the time by extracting hour, minute and second
t = TimeSerial(hour(.offset(0, 2)), minute(.offset(0, 2)), second(.offset(0, 2)), 0)
' Get the time by subtracting the `Date`-part
t = .offset(0, 2) - int(.offset(0, 2))
```

(2) I assume your problem comes from gluing together some *WorksheetFunctions*. But while you are in VBA, there is no need to use `WorksheetFunction` just to check if a value is between 2 other values. Just use an if-statement:

```
Dim t As Date   ' There is no Time datatype in VBA
t = TimeValue(cel.Offset(0, 2))
If t >= TimeValue("06:30:00") And t <= TimeValue("19:00:00") Then
    cel.Offset(0, 3) = "A"
Else
    cel.Offset(0, 3) = "B"
End If
```

or, if you prefer

```
cel.Offset(0, 3) = IIf(t >= TimeValue("06:30:00") And t <= TimeValue("19:00:00"), "A", "B")
```